# Unitary Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that a normal operator with unimodular eigenvalues is unitary. We are given a hint to try diagonalization.

I'm completely lost with even knowing where to begin this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V$ be a normal operator, then there is unitary operator $U$ and diagonal operator $D$ such that $V=UDU^{-1}$. For unimodular $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ always holds $\lambda^{-1}=\overline{\lambda}$, so $D^{-1}=D^*$. The rest is clear.